# Laravel 3 Snappy bundle Class Snappy not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I'm struggling to get the Snappy bundle to work.

It keeps telling me that the Snappy Class is not found.

I've installed the bundle and added it to the bundles.php file for auto loading.

But still nothing.

All help is appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

I had everything installed correctly but the issue was I should be using namespaces. On the bundle page it says the usage is something like this.

```
Bundle::start('snappy');
$snappy = Snappy::make('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://laravel.com');
exit;
```

The correct way to do this is to use the namespace like so

```
Bundle::start('snappy');

// the following two lines is added
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf; 
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://laravel.com');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the bundle using Artisan then (from a quick look at the bundles GitHub repository) you need to rename the folder `bundles/snappy-laravel-bundle` to just `snappy`. Or you can add in a `location` key in the bundles registration in `application/bundles.php`.

```
'snappy' => array('auto' => true, 'location' => 'snappy-laravel-bundle')
```

Laravel, by default, will assume that the key of the array (in this case `snappy`) is the directory that the bundle is stored in in the `bundles` directory.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out tonight and come back and mark your answer correct if it works :) thanks for your help so far.